# Ruby version is not updated in the applications enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I updated ruby to 2.2.2 with rbenv

`$ruby -v
 $ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin13]`

After I created a new rails application by `rails new xxx` and then `rails server`, [image]

Why the ruby version is still 2.0.0. How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: `rails` script has this for a shebang: `/usr/bin/env ruby`. Apparently, ruby resolved in this manner is still the system ruby (2.0.0). My guess is that you ran rails commands in an environment where your rbenv changes had no effect (another terminal session or something like that)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But what should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version

Answer (score 0):

You need to freeze Ruby version in two files:

**.ruby-version**

```
2.2.2
```

This file created automatically if you type *rbenv local 2.2.2*. The other file require to lock specific Ruby version is the following:

**Gemfile**

```
ruby '2.2.2'
...
```

Afterwards *bundle install* will fail in case of different Ruby version set as active.

Comment: Thanks, but can you expand a little bit on that?